# How do I make the text my button toggles to appear right next to my button instead of on a new line?

Tags: html

Here is my code i have

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function toggle(obj) {
      var obj=document.getElementById(obj);
      if (obj.style.display == "block") obj.style.display = "none";
      else obj.style.display = "block";
}

<body>

<button type="button" style="width: 150px; height: 50px;"
onClick="toggle('miniDisplay')"> minicom </button>
<div id="miniDisplay" style="display:none;">

<p style="text-align:center;">connect to minicom and display</p></div>
</body>
```

Currently the text displays a line under where the button is. I would like it to display on the same line. I know it is center aligned, it is just underneath the button on a different line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your div is a block level element, meaning that it will expand to take up the full width of its container. Change it to inline-block instead.

```
function toggle(obj) {
      var obj=document.getElementById(obj);
      if (obj.style.display == "inline-block") obj.style.display = "none";
      else obj.style.display = "inline-block";
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/k93Mp/)**

Comment: It still is putting the text underneath the button for me. I changed it to inline-block. In the fiddle it works, but if i try and center the text it doesn't move it in the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Change "block" to "inline-block" in your javascript.